# Group Glyphicon and text together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to group the Ticks and the Names together so that if a name goes onto a new line so does the tick and the full name

e.g.

[image]

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nydia Dahm
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Hillary Stano
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Mikki Rudisill
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Lashonda Hardcastle
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Starr Ewalt
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Geri Groen
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Armandina Foreman
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Alden Lusk
```

If I place the text into the span I seem to get extra spacing

https://jsfiddle.net/s7mtzt5f/

Comment: Umm.. Wrap them  in a div? Use `<br/>`. Are there restrictions or something.

Comment: When you place them into the span extra spacing is added. I want them on one line and only go onto another line when they have to

Comment: Those are styled using bootstrap to display glyphs. It messes with the styling. They are supposed to be empty. Not to mention `aria-hidden="true"` would mean screen readers would ignore them so putting content in there with that would also be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each group in a `<span>` and add the `white-space:nowrap` css style.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nydia Dahm</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Hillary Stano</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Mikki Rudisill</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Lashonda Hardcastle</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Starr Ewalt</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Geri Groen</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Armandina Foreman</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Alden Lusk</span>
```

**Update:** bradlis7  pointed out that bootstrap has a `text-nowrap` class that does the same thing as the above. You should definitely use `text-nowrap` to make the code more concise and bootstrap-compliant. Use it like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nydia Dahm</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Hillary Stano</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Mikki Rudisill</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Lashonda Hardcastle</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Starr Ewalt</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Geri Groen</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Armandina Foreman</span>
<span class="text-nowrap"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Alden Lusk</span>
```

Comment: Bootstrap also has the class `text-nowrap` that is a little more concise than `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: @bradlis7 awesome thanks, I didn't realize that. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nydia Dahm</div>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Hillary Stano<br/>
```

Either one of these should work.

Comment: I'd like as many a possible on one line and only go onto a new line when they have to, not forcing a newline Thank anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looking something like this one maybe.

```css
  span.full-name {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 
</head>
<body>
 <span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Nydia Dahm</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hillary Stano</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Mikki Rudisill</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lashonda Hardcastle</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Starr Ewalt</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Geri Groen</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Armandina Foreman</span>

<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Alden Lusk</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Reka Jape</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Mikki Rudisill</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lashonda Hardcastle</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Starr Ewalt</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Starr Ewalt</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Geri Groen</span>
<span class="full-name"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>Armandina Foreman</span>
</body>
```

Comment: That might causea someone issues as it would affect every span on a site. I would place the inline-flex into a class thanks for your answer.

Comment: @sw2020 yes nice catch. I just give you an example. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/bvzcu3ba/1/ ]